# Passing second argument to GNU parallel while feeding ls

Tags: gnu-parallel

I process files found by `ls` as

```
ls /folder/ | parallel -j20 ./command {}
```

but I need to pass the job number as well. I tried

```
ls /folder/ | parallel -j20 ./command {1} {2} ::: {1..20}
ls /folder/ | parallel -j20 ./command {} {} ::: {1..20}
```

but it does not work. I also tried `{#}` for passing the job number.

Comment: Note that you should never use the output of `ls` in a script. Using a `for` loop or `find` is always the better solution.

Comment: @mashuptwice may I ask why?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @mashuptwice oh thanks. I always work with well-formatted directories, and thus, never thought of that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the commands you are trying to run. Give us a few file names and then what number should be passed an how. Are you trying to launch things like `./command file1.txt 1` and `./command file2.txt 2` etc.?

Comment: @terdon `./command` script is irrelevant here. Consider it as a bash script with `echo "$1 $2"`. Yes, the aim is to run `/command file1.txt 1` or `/command 1 file1.txt`. The order is not important as I can change the arguments inside the script.

Answer (score 2):

The `{#}` replacement string should be exactly what you need here. For example, given

```
$ ls
 file1  'file2 with spaces'  'file3'$'\n''with'$'\n''newlines'   file4   file5
```

then

```
parallel --null echo {#} {} ::: *
1 file1
2 file2 with spaces
3 file3
with
newlines
4 file4
5 file5
```

or, if you have enough files to exceed the ARG_MAX limit you could use

```
printf '%s\0' * | parallel --null echo {#} {}
```

Comment: You could also just do `parallel --null echo {#} {} ::: *`.

Comment: @terdon good point - I'm overcomplicating things as usual...

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me what you want to do. Maybe one of these?

```
ls /folder/ | parallel -j20 ./command {1} {2} :::: - ::: {1..20}
ls /folder/ | parallel -j20 ./command {1} {2} :::: - :::+ {1..20}
ls /folder/ | parallel -j20 ./command {1} {#}
ls /folder/ | parallel -j20 ./command {1} {%}
```